# How do I wait to update an HTML header until promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, electron

I am building my first electron application and I am running into a JS error I am not sure how to fix. I have managed to setup the IPC for a basic password manager application. The use-case is simple:

1. I click an HTML button and the frontend connects to the backend and delivers a keyword from which to build a password.
2. Password is generated.
3. Upon completion, the password is returned to the frontend to be displayed via HTML in a header tag.

Here is an example of the expected behavior with the input string dog:
keyword --> dog
generated password --> dog-jdls4ksls

The issue I am seeing is that instead of printing the generated password, I am seeing:

```
[object Object]-jdls4ksls
```

My best guess is that, since I am using async/await, I am printing the promise memory object instead of the returned value. I do not know, however, how I would block to wait for completion. The code in question providing this output is the last line of render.js, which was called from the HTML body.

Any help would be appreciated!

For context, I am primarily a backend developer, with plenty of python and C/C++/C# experience. My goal is to rebuild a C#/.NET GUI application into an electron app.

Here is all my code.

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require("electron")
const path = require("path")

function generatePassword(keyword) {
    console.log(keyword)
    return keyword + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,12)
}

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        resizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('html/passwordGen.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    ipcMain.handle("generatePassword", generatePassword)
    // console.log(generatePassword('test string')) // works
    createWindow()
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error) // log error to console
    app.quit() // quit the app
})
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('main', {
    genPW: (keyword) => ipcRenderer.invoke("geåneratePassword", keyword)
})
```

render.js

```
async function testClick () {
    const pw_root = document.getElementById("keyword")
    const pw_label = document.querySelector("#password")
    pw_label.innerText = await window.main.genPW(pw_root.value)
}
```

passwordGen.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../render.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    <input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Please enter a keyword...">
    <button id="btn" onclick="testClick()">Generate Password</button>

    <h1 id="password"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Here is the code that worked. The accepted solution worked with the exception that I needed to either 1) keep the async/await on the generatePassword() or 2) convert it to .then() format as recommended in another solution.

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require("electron")
const path = require("path")

function generatePassword(keyword) {
    console.log(keyword)
    return keyword + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,12)
}

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        resizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('html/passwordGen.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    // ipcMain.handle("generatePassword", generatePassword)
    // console.log(generatePassword('stink')) // works
    ipcMain.handle('generatePassword', (_event, keyword) => {
        console.log(keyword); // Testing
        return generatePassword(keyword);
    });
    createWindow()
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error) // log error to console
    app.quit() // quit the app
})
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('main', {
    genPW: (keyword) => {
        return ipcRenderer.invoke("generatePassword", keyword)
    }
})
```

render.js

```
async function testClick () {
    const pw_root = document.getElementById("keyword")
    const pw_label = document.querySelector("#password")
    pw_label.innerText = await window.main.genPW(pw_root.value)
    // window.main.genPW(pw_root.value).then(res => {pw_label.innerText = res})
    // ^^^ works as well if async/await removed
}
```

Comment: "*My best guess is that, since I am using async/await, I am printing the promise memory object*" - no, that would print `[object Promise]`

Comment: What does `console.log(keyword)` log?

Comment: It logs the keyword, so in my example dog.

Comment: @Bergi I tried some suggestions in the comments below and it started to return object promise and I was able to resolve from there using your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close. Using Elctron's `invoke` method is the correct approach.

Within your `main.js` file, Electron's IPC `handle` signature contains the `channel` and `listener` arguments. In
your code you are calling your `generatePassword()` function in place of the `listener` argument. Instead, it should
be `(event, ...args)`. In your specific case `(event, keyword)`.
See [ipcMain.handle(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener)
for more information.

Additionally, within your `preload.js` script, all you need to do is add a `return` statement in front of your `ipcRenderer.invoke` method.

Finally, there is no need to use `async` on your `testClick()` function. Electron's `invoke` handles all of this.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        resizable: false,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

function generatePassword(keyword) {
    console.log(keyword)
    return keyword + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,12)
}

electronIpcMain.handle('generatePassword', (event, keyword) => {
    console.log(keyword); // Testing
    return generatePassword(keyword);
});
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'main', {
        genPW: (keyword) => {
            return ipcRenderer.invoke('generatePassword', keyword);
        }
    });
```

---

For sake of simplicity, I have included your `render.js` script within `<script>` tags below the closing `</body>` tag.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Emergency</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="password">

            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="generated-password">Generated Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="generated-password" disabled>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.main.genPW(document.getElementById('password').value)
                .then((generatedPassword) => {
                    document.getElementById('generated-password').value = generatedPassword;
                })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I used what you posted to solve my issue. I added the return statement, modified the event handler, and removed async/await as suggested. When I did, the label showed [object Promise]. I added async/await back and solved. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use async function as event listener, you need to use regular (not async) function here.

```
function testClick() {
    const pw_root = document.getElementById("keyword")
    const pw_label = document.querySelector("#password")
    window.main.genPW(pw_root.value).then(res => {pw_label.innerText = res})
}
```

also, you have typo here: `invoke("geåneratePassword")`

Comment: "*I dont think you can use async function as event listener*" - sure you can, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: using async/await solved my issue, though I am going to try this and see if it works as well. thanks!

Comment: This solution works, but I also needed to modify the event listener in main as well to add the event.

Answer (score -1):

Try using double await as in
`await (await callToBackend)`

Comment: This is never necessary